# Installing Ubuntu 19.10 on 2nd drive modifies 1st drive. How to recover?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, ssd

First a little detour. Today I tried **Manjaro ArchLinux** on my Desktop PC with 2 SSDs. I installed it on the second drive, it created a bootloader there. So in the BIOS I could set the second drive to boot or choose during BIOS startup (F12). This was the expected behavior for me.

Then I installed **Ubuntu 19.10** on the second drive. The second drive didn't get a bootloader, it won't boot when selected from BIOS or via F12. Instead Ubuntu (unexpectedly) modified my first (Windows) SSD and created a bootloader with selection menu there. At the same time the first SSD was changed so the Gigabyte BIOS is (strangely) not picking it up anymore to be set as a regular boot drive in the BIOS menu. Instead I can only choose it manually during the boot process (via F12). Annoying.

**Finally my three questions**:

1. Why did Ubuntu change a SSD it was not installed to - without even asking?
2. How do I get my Windows SSD back to normal - being recognized by BIOS and removing the Linux boot menu.
3. How do I get Ubuntu starting from the second drive on its own?

Answer (score 0):

See launchpad bugs 1396379, 1779488, and 1173457 (and add yourself to the "does this affect me?" list for each.  Basically, the Ubuntu installer picks the first EFI partition it sees (on sda) to install the UEFI Ubuntu bootloaders.

Since you have an EFI partition already on the second disk, you can simply copy all the files from the first disk's EFI to the second, and you will have a working boot on the second disk.

You can remove UEFI boot entries with efibootmgr, so you can remove Ubuntu from the list.  Then you can remove the excess ubuntu directory in the EFI ( .../EFI/ubuntu). Finally, probably the installer put the ubuntu bootloader in .../EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi, and renamed the (Windows) original default bootloader to a backup -- rename the backup to bootx64.efi.

Comment: In 379, I posted a work around to install to some other drive than sda or first drive. I just had to do that again with install of 19.10. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
 After you copy files from sda's ESP to sdb's ESP, you have to use efibootmgr to add new entry using those files. If external drive UEFI will automatically use boot files in /EFI/Boot which you also should copy even if internal drive.